# How to get Json in order which is defined in database table through Java or SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, collections

I am working on computing json format data to use it as Navbar. I have already made the json but there is a column in my database table which specify the order of the menu so I want to return the json on that order only.

My database table is like this:

[image: This is my database table]

My Java code is:

```
  String sql="select menu,submenu,link,menu_order from test1";
while(resultSet.next()) {
            String menu = resultSet.getString("menu");

            String subMenu = resultSet.getString("submenu");
            String link = resultSet.getString("link");

            map.compute(menu, (key, subMenus) -> {
                Map<String, String> mapSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                mapSubMenu.put("type", subMenu);
                mapSubMenu.put("link", link);

                subMenus = subMenus != null ? subMenus : new ArrayList<>();

                //check for empty or null string otherwise return empty ArrayList
                if(!"".equalsIgnoreCase(subMenu) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(link))
                 subMenus.add(mapSubMenu);

                return subMenus;
            });
            str = gson.toJson(map);
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```

I am getting json from this code like this

```
   {
  "India": [
    {
      "type": "delhi",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "mumbai",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "australia": [
    {
      "type": "sydney",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "melbourn",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "spain": [
    {
      "type": "valencia",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "madrid",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "logout": [

  ]
}
```

It is displaying data as it is present in my database table, but I have a column as **menu_order** which defines what should be the order of menu and acc to that there sub menu will come.

How can I achieve that at the Java end or from query end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an ORDER BY on your query

```
String sql="select menu,submenu,link,menu_order from test1 ORDER BY menu_order";
```